# How to enter recursive edit mode and abort command inside it?

Tags: emacs

I used to be confident of returning to buffer from mini-buffer by just pressing <kbd>C-g</kbd> once, until I learned there is a "recursive-edit-mode" inside Emacs [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recursive-Edit.html#Recursive-Edit), which seems to make cancellation action inconsistent. Therefore, I am reading the entire section in hope of finding a more consistent / stateless command to return to mini-buffer.

However, I encountered below problems when following and trying to replicate what the manual says:

1. Entering Recursive-edit-mode: After "M-x query-replace RET C-r" (in `Fundamental-mode`), I could not replicate "a pair of square brackets" in mode-line. However, now I DO have to press `C-g` TWICE to return back to buffer.
   Question: Does recursive-edit-mode still have square brackets now? (I am using ver 24.3)
2. Quitting: The manual directs me to the [Quitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html#Quitting) section for quitting command. It says *Aborting with <kbd>C-]</kbd> (abort-recursive-edit) is used to get out of a recursive editing level and cancel the command which invoked it*. So I tried it out within "M-x query-replace RET C-r", hoping one `C-]` will get me out from minibuffer to buffer, but it still takes 2 shots to do that.
   Question: Is this normal? If yes, any other command to guarantee command abortion and return to buffer with 1 execution?

Just want to brush frequently used command such as `C-g`. If made consistent, it may help avoid inputs being eaten (sometimes unnoticed) by the minibuffer due to trapped inside recursive-edit-mode.
Visually confirming point each time inside the buffer makes keyboard input an closed-loop feedback process and thus consumes more attention, though.

Comment: +1 to @phils's suggestion of `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode`.  And if you use the tiny library [`mb-depth+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/mb-depth%2b.el) then you can choose the depth indicator format and the face.

Comment: @phils, thanks for the tips. I added the `(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode 1)`, now I do have a square bracket in echo area with level number inside it, even better.

Comment: On the tangential topic of recursive *minibuffers* (and indicators thereof), if you have `(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)` then you definitely also want `(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode 1)`

Comment: The square brackets around the mode line during recursive edits do seem to be there, but I'm not sure the documentation is still accurate in terms of how to demonstrate this. However it does give the example of entering the debugger, and if you do so (e.g. `M-: (debug) RET`) then you'll see the square brackets as described.

Comment: @phils, great example. It is all clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You definitely will see square brackets in the mode line for a recursive edit -- but not for a recursive minibuffer.
2. `C-g` does act consistently, but it does different things in different contexts (always the same thing for a given context, however). That can be confusing. It can take some getting used to - a bit like it takes getting used to the various behaviors of `C-g` during Isearch, depending on the current search state.
3. If you use recursive edits or recursive minibuffers then you need to pay attention to clues wrt the current state/context. Again, this is like learning Isearch. `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode` is a must, to provide feedback about what state you are in.
4. FWIW, beyond `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode`, I use a standalone minibuffer frame, and with each recursive edit or recursive minibuffer the background hue is changed slightly, to better indicate the level etc. (The background color changes slightly also for (a) active minibuffer and (b) Isearch. I use library [`oneonone.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el) for these things.)
5. If you don't use  a standalone minibuffer frame then you might consider highlighting the square brackets or something else in the mode line, to help you tell where you are at.
6. `C-r` during query-replace is a good example of when a recursive edit can be useful. There are a few others. But generally I do not make much use of recursive edits, FWIW. (I do, however, use recursive minibuffers a lot, because I use keys bound in minibuffer maps that do invoke commands that themselves might prompt for input etc.)
7. Wrt your question about `query-replace` with `C-r`: There is no minibuffer involved at all, here. And `C-]` after `C-r` does end not only the recursive edit but also the query-replace (whereas `C-M-c` ends the recursive edit and returns to the query-replace.
8. FWIW - In [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) interactions, you might find yourself within any number of recursive minibuffers. (For example, you might use [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) to successively narrow the set of completion candidates, and each narrowing opens a recursive minibuffer.)
9. `C-g` always aborts the current command, or if there is none then the current minibuffer, and `C-]` always aborts the current minibuffer. Repeating `C-g` (or `C-]`) pops back up the minibuffer chain, a level at a time. But (in **Icicles**) you can use `C-M-S-t` (aka `C-M-T`) to pop directly back to the top level (exit all minibuffers).
10. Similarly, answering a minibuffer prompt (e.g. hitting `RET` or using `mouse-2` on a candidate in `*Completions*`) exits the current minibuffer, popping up a level (to the parent minibuffer or to the top level if there is none). (In **Icicles** `RET` can optionally put you back at top level.)

Comment: Great explanations. A lot to digest. For point 9, you are correct, `C-]` get me all the way out of `M-x query-replace RET C-r`. Just now I typed `M-r` by typo inside `query-replace` and it interestingly levels in (like indefinitely.). That one could not be exited using `C-]`.

Comment: Sounds like `Icicles` is the way to go. I 'll play with the lib when I get familiar with the loading section.

Comment: **Icicles** is not necessarily the way to go. It is the way *I* go. ;-) I mention it here especially because it is how I use these things. Most Emacs users rarely use recursive minibuffers, and their use of the minibuffer is brief (for each use): they enter an answer to a prompt. With **Icicles** a lot typically goes on in the minibuffer.

Comment: `M-r` should just end your `query-replace` - it does for me, including after starting with `emacs -Q`. You probably have it bound to something out of the ordinary...